# Click after removing disabled from button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery I want to submit a button that was previously disabled. When I remove the attr of `disable` then do a `.click()` it doesn't trigger and send me to the next page. But if I do an `alert("XYZ");` then `.click()` it sends me to the next page. I assume this has to with the time taken to disable then click(It's not disabling before the click event is fired).

**Working Example Of "Broken" Behavior**: http://jsfiddle.net/LmFjd/71/ - This is how I have my code setup and exactly what is not working for me. Notice that it triggers the onsubmit event, but it doesn't actually submit.

**Working Example Of Expected Behavior**: If you put a `.show()` in there it works: http://jsfiddle.net/LmFjd/70/

When there is an alert between the removeAttr and the click() it works, otherwise the click doesn't trigger.

For clarification, I'm using jquery-1.5.1.min.js. It's a JSP page, using Apache Tomcat 6.0.29. It's a spring MVC WebApp, and I'm using the section inside a jQuery UI Dialog dismiss button

**Hackish Solution**: Putting a `.show()` before the `.click()` makes it work.

Comment: Please provide actual code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: `.attr()` is synchronous, so a subsequent call to `click()` won't fire until `attr()` is complete. [Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/LmFjd/) If there's a timing issue, it could only be because some *asynchronous* code has been introduced.

Comment: #1. That website is awesome Patrick, Thanks for introducing me.
#2. The code given works on that site, but not on mine, and I'm not sure, but I know now it's not a timing issue.

Comment: It's *extremely* handy for testing code. Be sure to explore the options on the left, including choosing a library (or none), being able to load other scripts, and choosing the placement of code, or the "DOM ready" approach.

Comment: This is a side issue, but change `"onClick"` to `"onclick"` since that's the correct capitalization to reach the `onclick` property. [Here's another example](http://jsfiddle.net/VETsb/1/) that includes everything in your code except the `.dialog()`. I don't know how the elements relate to that method, but it may play a role.

Comment: I can see it remove the disable from the button(The button becomes usable), but the click just doesn't fire. It's the darnedest thing.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but is your `onclick` defined inline?  If so, then you're removing it prior to calling `click`, so there is no click handler when you call `click`.  After the code executes, does actually clicking on the button work?  http://jsfiddle.net/VETsb/2/

Comment: What would actionButton do when clicked?

Comment: Nicholas: And it still doesn't work if you remove `$( this ).dialog( "close" );`? Is there any other code that comes into play? Is the `click` event also being assigned somewhere during this operation? Try loading `jQueryUI` into jsFiddle, and creating a working demo that others can test. There's just not enough info in the question to provide much of an answer.

Comment: When removing the dialog close nothing happens, but that's because it's a modal and blocks events beneath it. The click event is only tied to that one button.

Comment: @Lourens: It will click a button, that should take you to another page. When I add the alert between them it takes me to the other page, otherwise it just sits there.

Comment: Okay, so it is clicking the button, but for whatever reason it's moving to the next page, any reason for this?

Comment: You can try jquery trigger method. It is moving to the next page because the button is a submit button. and probably it is inside a form.

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. It's *not* moving to the next page. I do a trigger('submit') and trigger('click') and neither leads to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two things can be done through JQuery to do your things is Just remove the attributed disabled=disabled and on document ready use the hide and on doing some even again show you required input box, the code to do that is as under:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#edit').hide();
    "Discard changes": function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        alert(actionButton);
        $('#edit').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: On a hunch I tried something and it made me laugh that it works. If I put a .show() before the click, even though the button is already showing, it still triggers it...

Comment: can u provide the exact code to do this thing, on http://lawmirror.com/books/order.php?passed=&book=dipc08 there are three forms and showing them differently as required by user, as without proper code I can't tell what is wrong